# Как вывести события определенной категории?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь вывести события из одной категории, но выводятся все
Вот ссылка на доки
http://dev.timepad.ru/widget/list-widget-settings/

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" defer="defer" charset="UTF-8" src="https://timepad.ru/js/tpwf/loader/min/loader.js" data-timepad-customized="29248" data-timepad-apidomain="timepad.ru" data-timepad-widget-v2="event_list3">
(function() {
return {
  debug: true,
  display: "popup",
  requestOptions: {
    categories_include: {"379"},
  },
}
})();
</script>
```

Comment: _"// Нужные категории (id через запятую)"_ там строку передают, а не объект. и обратите внимание на второй снизу абзац желтым http://dev.timepad.ru/widget/how-widget-works/ Хз правда почему.

Answer (score 0):

согласно документации

> `categories_include?: string`    // Нужные категории (id через запятую)

должна передаваться строка, вы же передаете объект. Измените код на

```
categories_include: "379",
```

Еще по какой-то причине разработки в документации пишут следующее:

> Внимание! Не опускайте кавычки у названий параметров — это допускает JavaScript, но не JSON. По той же причине не используйте одинарные кавычки вместо двойных.

То есть просят указывать в виде `"categories_include": "370"`. Мне, правда, не ясно для чего это. возможно, как-то сериализуют объекты в JSON-строку не с помощью `JSON.stringify`, а с помощью непонятно чего.

```js
var a = { field: "value" };

console.log(a.toString())
```